# go to a class link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using lightbox image viewer and I want to add a button on image viewer where it says download. When they click it, they will be taken to an external link.

Lightbox already uses a href so I added a class.

I just need to make it like

http://www.websitetogo.com = a class

a class = thisiswheretogo

location.href = 'thisiswheretogo' ;

sorry for my bad explanation

**HTML**

```
<a href="img/image viewer/the-infinity.png" rel="lightbox" class="http://www.websitetogo.com" >...</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   $lightbox.find('.download').on('click', function(e) {
     location.href = 'class' ;
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: `window.location = $('.className').attr('href');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) are considered a better solution for storing arbitrary data against the DOM. This data can later be retrieved via [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```html
<a href="img/image viewer/the-infinity.png" rel="lightbox" data-external-link="http://www.google.com/">Image</a>
```

```js
$lightbox.find('.download').on('click', function(e) {
    window.location.href = $(this).data('external-link');
    return false;
});
```

The Lightbox plugin itself could be improved by utilising data attributes:

```html
<a href="viewer/the-infinity.png" data-media-type="img/image" data-external-link="http://www.google.com/" rel="lightbox">Image</a>
```

Comment: hi matt it say undefined. :(

Comment: Right, because the `.download` button is not the original lightbox link with our fancy data attribute. What lightbox plugin are you using?

Comment: this http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/       i just want to add button where it say download and cancel/exit  like this http://www.isacfabian.com/Untitled.png    thanks for your help

Comment: you can also inspect it here if you have time i appreciate http://www.isacfabian.com/

Comment: @AezacFabian I can't see any easy way to pass a value to the download button in Lightbox2. I'd consider replacing it with [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) which has much more customisation potential. A potential solution with Colorbox: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/colorbox/xgnaWK7fSGw

Comment: :( 503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.  why XD why XD sorry for disturbi'm still un lucky